# TTL to RS485 board blowing up

Tags: rs485

I recently started to explore energy meters with the ability to transmit data over RS485.

The specific meter I'm using is an Eastron SDM72D V2. I made a simple program to request data from the meter by requesting specific registers and it works without any problem. To perform continuous measurements I hook up a raspberry pi to an "TTL to RS485" board like the one attached and started to receive data. After a few days the "TTL to RS485" becomes inactive and to my surprise it had literally blown up. I have used 3 boards by now always with the same result after a few days (blowup MAX485 chip). I'm not sure the chip is a clone as it has no markings.

The connections are very simple just directly connected ground and vcc to the raspberry pi and TX and RX to the pins for the serial out on the raspberry. Then connected the A and B directly to the eastron energy meter.

The raspberry pi is powered by a din rail power supply and the energy meter is powered directly from the powerlines it is measuring.

This worked well at the beginning without any blowout but it seems to have start happening after a second EV charger install where we sometimes have 2 7.4kW chargers working. I suspect probably some static discharge but I really don't know the cause or how to prevent this situation.

Please let me know any ideas to protect the "TTL to RS485" against this blowouts.
Thanks!

Image of a blown out "TTL to RS485" (visible hole in the "MAX485" chip, sometimes it only creates a small bump):
[image]

EDIT:
I have tested both with or without ground connection to the meter with the same results.
The boards have been purchased from alibaba so probably counterfeit as they were also very cheap. I have a different model purchased from a local electronics store which is slightly different and has the ic markings (please check attached photo). I might test this one next to see if the same outcome arises.

[image]

Update:
Sorry for the late update but had higher priority tasks, now I'm back at tackling this issue. Here is what I have tried since last time:

- Connecting the ground between meter and the "TTL to RS485"
- Connecting the ground between meter, "TTL to RS485" and Earth
- Used the "TTL to RS485" with the IC markings from a local reputable electronics store (no grounds)

All cases resulted in a blown up "TTL to RS485" module..

I'm now thinking that it may be the meter that is out of spec in a way. Nevertheless I have yet a final test which is to use an USB to RS485 adapter, a configuration I'm using in a working installation for more than an year with the same model of meters (3 of then instead of just 1 on a single RS485 bus) but with a rpi4B.

I will post the results once I managed to complete both experiments (using the same meter and the USB adapter and changing the meter altogether).

Also is there any way to validade if the meter's RS485 is busted in any way that is making the "TTL to RS485" to blow up?

Comment: What appears to be Chinese characters in the lower right of the circuit board does not inspire confidence. You may not be aware, but there are many counterfeit ICs coming from disreputable suppliers located in China. If you purchased the board from AliExpress, you may just be out of luck. However, assuming you have a good board, could you supply a diagram for the RS485 circuit, showing the items it is connected to, the ground(s), and the termination resistors?

Comment: Is the heat damage on the left caused by soldering, or the fault?

Comment: How come there was no0V connection to the meter?  The protection will probably not work in that situation. You must connect the 0V from the board to the meter.

Comment: I understand that 接大地 means "connect to ground"

Comment: Seems there is no 0V connection on the meter. I’d suggest using an isolated RS485 interface.

Comment: I have tested with the 0V connection to the meter and without it has well. The only visual damaged caused by the fault is really the hole on the ic the other markings are from soldering paste. I have purchased this boards from alibaba but at the time really didn't know much about RS485 so looked for the cheapest

Comment: Any form of data communication assumes that all nodes have the same voltage and ground potentials. Otherwise nothing will work and things might blow up. In case of RS485 that does indeed mean either ground everything together or use galvanic isolation with a secondary grounded towards the target.

Comment: Also that MAX485 definitely looks like it could be a fishy copy cat part. "The boards have been purchased from alibaba" Congrats, it's the best way to buy cheap, broken electronics. Buying broken electronics from reliable vendors is much more expensive.

Comment: The point labelled "接大地" **must** be connected to the meter's ground point. RS485 is *not* a current loop and has some hard limits in the spec for allowable common-mode voltage range. The A/B side of the transceiver must share the same ground reference as whatever it's talking to. Make sure that you're connecting to the *right* ground point at the meter - it may have an isolated RS485 output in which case simply using the enclosure as ground will not work and could just as easily result in the situation you're seeing.

Comment: @Lundin - "... that all nodes have the same voltage and ground potentials". That's not quite accurate.  So long as you stay withing the guaranteed common mode voltage range of your receiver (-7 V to + 12 V for '485 receivers), you should be OK.

Comment: How do you have it wired?  Do you have terminating resistors (not that that would cause problems on input side of driver)? [UART TTL to RS485 Two-way Converter](https://www.elecrow.com/uart-ttl-to-rs485-twoway-converter-p-1545.html)

Answer (score 5):

It would be nice if you would provide a pseudo-schematic or block diagram of your setup, with details of how the power and grounds are hooked up.

But even without seeing that, I'm going to guess that for some reason you're exceeding the common mode voltage range (Vcm) of your '485 receiver.  Most '485 receivers have a Vcm of -7 V to +12 V, though some may be better than this.  If you exceed this range, you could damage the receiver.

The hole in the IC package would also be consistent with this kind of failure, in that you need enough energy to blow a hole in the package.  Localized heating of the IC die could do this.  So could a blown/fused bond wire.  I do not think (though I cannot say for sure) that a typical ESD like event would do this (lightning strikes aside).  But a load dump (suddenly removing a high current load from the system) could cause a voltage shift between the various grounds with enough energy available that could cause this kind of damage.

You said the problem started or has gotten worse after the second EV charger was installed.  This also points to a ground (return) shift, or ground difference between the meter and your '485 board.

Answer (score 3):

If the basic functionality works, but several boards have been destroyed, either the boards are below specification or your environment is more hazardous than typical.

Consider using

- high-quality branded convertors
- better ESD protection
- isolation

I've had good results from Digilen isolated RS-485 boards, but many manufacturers are available.

Also, I understand that 接大地 means "connect to ground", but it appears that it hasn't been soldered to.  You can get difficulties with this.

I strongly recommend reading Bob Perrrin's indispensible [Art and Science of RS-485](https://www2.htw-dresden.de/%7Ehuhle/ArtScienceRS485.pdf), especially the portions about grounding.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will for sure look into the Art and Science of RS-485. I'm getting convinced that boards I purchased are the culprit.

Comment: The most common property of cheap board and parts is that they work under good conditions and fail more readily under poorer conditions.  The property of well-made devices is they really do perform like the datasheets say, and their extra cost goes into testing, QA, documentation etc.

Comment: The use of this particular phrase "大地" specifically refers to the *Earth* ground, otherwise it would just be a ground (地). So yeah, it's possibly an ESD issue due to insufficient protection. Connecting it to PE might reduce the possibility of damage, and this might be why they've put a notice here...